# import html table to datatable in c#

Tags: c#

I wanted to import some data from HTML table to a datatable. From what I've read the best way to do it is to use HTML Agility. This is the code I used to do so but I'm getting error

> 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\webbrowser\WebBrowserControlDialogs\MainForm.cs.

This is the error line :

```
otable.Rows.Add(row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray());
```

Any idea on how to fix this ? Appreciated

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
var document = webBrowser1.Document;
var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;

var content = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.outerHTML;

doc.LoadHtml(content);

DataTable otable = new DataTable();
otable.Columns.Add("ID .", typeof(string));
otable.Columns.Add("Art.", typeof(string));
otable.Columns.Add("E ram", typeof(int));
otable.Columns.Add("Hour", typeof(string));
otable.Columns.Add("S", typeof(int));
otable.Columns.Add("Ref", typeof(double));

foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr/td"))
{
    otable.Rows.Add(row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray());
    //...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) that lets you use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) extension methods. Add this to the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If you get the error `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source` when trying to call `row.SelectNodes("td").Select(..)`, this means that `row.SelectNodes("td")` is `null`. You should correct your code and/or include appropriate null checking. I think that you want to select the `tr`s at first, and then you can do `SelectNodes("td")` to get the cells.

```
foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr"))
{
    otable.Rows.Add(row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray());
}
```